# How to switch between Oracle 11g and 12c on same linux

Tags: linux, oracle-11g, oracle-12c

I have oracle11g and 12c installed on same machine and few test cases that need to be run on both versions.
Can power up both database simultaneously and run tests parallely.
Do you know any document that describe this scenario of multiple oracle on same machine.

Note: I am not from DB background and just using it for something so please suggest accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Check the `/etc/oratab` file. In there the `ORACLE_HOME` is defined in the second field. Make sure that both instances point to the right `ORACLE_HOME`. If you do an  `. oraenv` to change from one instance to another this scripts sets the correct `ORACLE_HOME` so you connect with the right binaries to start, stop, and access the instance. The file is normally also used to stat-up the instances at boot time.

Example of a line in the `/etc/oratab` file:

```
DEVA:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_2:Y
```

`DEVA` is the name (`SID`) of the instance, `/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_2` is the `ORACLE_HOME`, and `Y` indicates that the instance must be started at boot time.

You say that you have no DB background so be aware that you cannot run the same instance in both versions of Oracle.

Answer (score -2):

Check AskTom webpage - [Installed multiple home(11g and 12c on same windows server) unable to connect to 11G DB- Error - ORA-12514](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9527209900346397635)

> Connor said...
>
> > When you start the 11g service/instance, it will register with the listener, and then it should be able to recieve remote connections.
> >
> > If you want to be able to connect to a currently-down 11g instance via the 12c listener, you might have to edit listener.ora to explicitly list the sid you want to accept connections from, eg, something like adding:
> >
> > ```
> > (SID_DESC =
> > (SID_NAME = xxx)
> > (ORACLE_HOME = c:\oracle\product\11.2.0.4)
> > (ORACLE_SID = xxx)
> > )
> > ```
> >
> > into the sid list.

I think, will be hard without DB background, but it is possible.